# "No signal" on 4K monitor after login, reconnect hdmi cable get back the signal (Windows 7)

Tags: display, remote-desktop, hdmi

Setup: Windows 7 pro. Single 4K monitor connected to PC via HDMI cable.
Running 4K resolution.

Issue: Once logined remotely, you are greeted with a login screen.
Login locally, "No signal" on 4K monitor after login, reconnect hdmi cable get back the signal  and 4k resolution.

Question: how to fix it without reconnect hdmi cable which will force a resize on all application windows.

Comment: And the question is?????????

Comment: Try checking it with other HDMI monitors, or using DisplayPort. After that I'd try a graphics driver update check - it could be that the drivers for your graphics chip are not meant for 4K and have bugs when displaying large resolutions. Find out the model of your graphics card if you don't know, and if it's an old model it's very likely it'll need a driver update to support newer standards.

Comment: @Jonah, the graphics card is capable to drive 4k. driver is latest. Do not have another 4K monitor. It never happens in 1920x1080 monitors.